# Best Practice for form submission when there are multiple forms on a single page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, multiple-forms

If, for whatever reason, a project demanded that a single page contain more than one form, are there any best practices for error handling of incomplete forms when one of the forms gets submitted before others?

In other words, let’s say we have two forms on a single page: `’myCat’` and `’myDog’`; and those forms have three input boxes: `’catName’`, `’catColor’`, `’catSpecies’` and a submit button (`’myDog’` has three input boxes: `’dogName’`, `’dogColor’`, `’dogSpecies’` and its own submit button) .  Now, we have to be prepared for the user that makes a few entries on one form, but doesn’t submit it before proceeding to another form and submitting that one.  If, for instance, a user enters a value for `’catName’`, and then proceeds to complete all of the `’myDog’` entries and submits the `’myDog’` form, it seems like the user should be asked if they prefer to save the `’catName’` entry as well.  (I recognize that this example is best solved with two fieldsets in the same form.  I use the example as an illustration.)

Are there any examples or recommendations for how to evaluate incomplete forms and warn users before they unknowingly navigate away from or refresh a page as the result of a form submission?

Answer (score 1):

Collect all info from the forms in one `FormData` object, validate it and submit it in case all is ok, for example.

```
document.getElementById('btnName').onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    function valid(obj){
        // validation check
        if(){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    var fd = new FormData();
    var obj = {},
        frm, fld;
    for (var f = 0; f < document.forms.length; f++) {
        frm = document.forms[f];
        for (var e = 0; e < frm.elements.length; e++) {
            fld = frm.elements[e];
            obj[fld.name] = fld.value;
        }
    };


    if(valid(obj)){
        for (i in obj){
            fd.append(i, obj[i]);
        }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", f.action);
        // 
        xhr.send(fd);
    }else{
        // for example
        alert('something is wrong';)
    }

}
```

less mess in central part:

```
    var obj = {};
    document.forms.forEach(function(frm){
        frm.forEach(function(el){
            obj[el.name] = el.value;
        });
    });
```

In case of leaving the page with filled form: put an event on `window.onbeforeunload` and ask if user wants to leave.

Simple validation to check if anything is filled:

```
function anyFilled(){
    var obj = {};
    document.forms.forEach(function(frm){
        frm.forEach(function(el){
            if(el.value)
                //some decoration
                el.style.border = 'solid 2px red';
                return true
        });
    });
    return false
}
```

Comment: Waiting for your example

Comment: I'd be hesitant to submit the value for `’catName’` (from the example above) because I think we need to consider the user who did not complete the `’myCat’` form because they did not want it to be saved.

Comment: I think the `onbeforeunload` event idea is a good one, but I'd like to find a way to evaluate if entries have been made in forms that did not include the button that triggered the submission so that the user is only asked if they want to leave if there are partially complete forms.  I hate those "do you really want to leave?" messages, and I think we should avoid using them for every submission and limit them to unique instances.

Comment: just check if something if any of fields is filled in the forms and then ask/don't ask

Answer (score 1):

**FOR AFTER FORM VALIDATION:** One thing I would do is if there is an error for a specific field, change the border color of that field to red or something that would catch your eye, and then display the error right next to the field. This way the user knows which exact field has an error, and what they can do to fix it.

Comment: It would be great if that could be done in one form if the user starts to enter data in another form before submitting the first.  I'm not sure how to trigger validation by simply leaving a form.

Comment: I tried wrapping two forms inside another and tried submitting the wrapping form and that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Call form-Validation upon submission of the myDog Form, where you first check the blanck/other validations of the myCat-Form. If not valid then return false/show error message.

You can set a hidden field, if the my cat form submission is done, then set its value say '1' on the submission of myDog form check the hidden field value/myCat form fields, then show error.

Comment: I like the idea of the hidden field.  But maybe the way to approach it would be for its default value to be '0', and then use `onchange` events in each of the input fields to set the hidden field to '1' if an entry was made in any input box.  A '1' would then signify that work had been done in that form but it had not been submitted.  As you suggested, myDog would check the hidden field value in myCat and show an error if it equaled '1'.

Comment: You just put a single hidden field under myCat form, if the myCat form submission is done change it to '1', if user submitted the form (server side validation if any) change it '2' else '0'. When you submit myDog check the status value 0/1/2, if status is 0/2 call the myCat validate function.